# Versions of Schur's Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, lie-algebras

So I'm readying Humphreys's Introduction to Lie Algebras.

https://www.math.uci.edu/~brusso/humphreys.pdf

On page 38 of the PDF he states this version of Schur's Lemma:

> Let $\phi:L \to gl(V)$ be an irreducible representation of a
>   Lie-algebra $L$.
>
> Then the only endomorphisms of $V$ commuting with all $\phi(L)$ are
>   the scalars.

Now, I have seen another version, with two parts:

> 1. Let $V$ be an irreducible $L$-module, then $End(V)$ is a skew field
> 2. If these are over an algebraically closed field $k$ , $End(V) \cong k$

My questions are:

1. If I prove the second formulation, not only the commuting elements are scalars but all elements of $End(V)$; no? Why is this statement much stronger?
2. If I wanted to derive the first formulation from the second would it proceed as such:

Let $\phi$ be an irreducible representation of $L$. $\phi$ defines $V$ as an $L$-module - that is $V$ is irreducible. So by the second formulation $End(V) \cong k$, specifically, all the elements commuting with all $\phi(L)$ are scalars

?

Can you help me clarify these please?

Comment: Isn't the general assumption in Humphreys' book that the base field is always algebraic closed of characteristic zero?

Comment: @yes yes, I edited my question ; I still would like feedback to the other questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing two definitions of endomorphism. In Humphrey's version, the word "endomorphism" refers to endomorphisms of $V$ as an abstract vector space (i.e. we forget it has the structure of an $L$-module).

The endomorphisms of $V$ as an $L$-module, however, are defined to be those endomorphisms of $V$ as a vector space which commute with $\varphi(x)$ for all $x \in L$. This is what $End(V)$ refers to in the second version.

I think it's fairly obvious that the two are equivalent if you have the correct definitions in mind. At least the equivalency of Humphrey's version and the second part of the second version should be clear. If you remove the assumption that the underlying field is algebraically closed then you get the first part.

Comment: Humphreys defines an L-module homomorphism as $\phi(x.v) = x.\phi(v)$. Is this what you mean by commutes here? Also, when proving the second part of the second formulation, there is no use I can see of commuting, see here page 139 for the proof: https://books.google.co.il/books?id=bOElBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=schur%27s+lemma+algebraically+closed+module&source=bl&ots=bZR28mrfbg&sig=1eaV-5oOl2MP5bz2NC7k10F-QxU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis5e2hgfXTAhXSSxoKHXmLDygQ6AEISTAG#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Ok, I understand now. thanks!